# Laravel Scout, search only get 20 items

Tags: php, laravel, search, full-text-search, laravel-scout

I'm using Laravel Scout, when I search and get the result, it only return exact 20 items, while there are actually more to get, in my case there are 56 items. How can I retrieve all items?

```
$products = Product::search($keyword)->get(); //this return 20 items
```

But when I count, there are 56 items

```
$products = Product::search($keyword)->count(); //this return 56
```

I tried to workaround by using the paginate() method with a large number as the argument to get all results. However, it appears not possible due to performance issues and the number can be very fluctuate.

```
$products = Product::search($keyword)->paginate(1000000); //this is bad practice
```

How can I retrieve all items when search in Laravel Scout?

Comment: You cannot get all results, as the maximum that Elastic is capable of returning is 10.000.
See https://github.com/ErickTamayo/laravel-scout-elastic/issues/82#issuecomment-332505507

Comment: check config/scout.php , 'paginate' => null, then ->paginate();

Answer (score 0):

For scenarios where you need all results and the total count isn't very large, you could dynamically set the pagination based on the count of the results. **However, be cautious with this approach due to its potential impact on performance**:

```
$totalCount = Product::search($keyword)->count();
$products = Product::search($keyword)->paginate($totalCount);
```